# are these functions and chaining of functions differentiable?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, limits

[image]

it seems that (a) is not because the sided limites are not the same
for (b), can i say that because of the chain rule it apllies that it is not differentiable as well ?
and for (c) it seems that for all x it is diffrentiable except 1/9.

Not 100% sure about my answers yet.

Comment: For part b you have to test the limits. The chain rule cannot tell you the answer if g is not differentiable.

Comment: Ok so how can i show it ?

Comment: Go back to the definition of derivatives with limits, show that the derivatives at 1/9 from two sides are equal (differentiable) or not equal (not differentiable). In this case I believe it's differentiable.